# Word mailmerge using multiple values to insert a block of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am trying to check if a field has one of multiple values then output a block of text. 
example: IF a field has the values of MB-75 or MB-100 or MB-200 then output a block of text
I thought I had it set up based on the post, but keep getting an error.

Error! Unknown op code for conditional.

{IF{={IF{MERGEFIELD Specialty1} = "MB-75" 1 0}+{IF{MERGEFIELD Specialty1} = "MB-100" 1 0} + {IF{MERGEFIELD Specialty1}="MB-200" 1 0}} 1 0}}=1 "Insert MB text" "False"}

Answer (score 0):

Found this and it worked:
I’ve found that if the condition contains a merge field and there is no space between it and the equals sign, then this error is produced after an Aspose mail merge.